# Why is this simple array based event emitter order sensitive?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, eventemitter

Simple event emitter does not fire an event handler if it is preceded by a '.once' event handler. Cannot understand why this happens.

```js
const emitter = (host = {}, listeners = {}) => Object.assign(host, {
  emit (event, data) {
    (listeners[event] || []).forEach(h => h(data))
  },
  on (event, handler) {
    if (!listeners[event]) listeners[event] = []
    listeners[event].push(handler)
    return () => host.off(event, handler)
  },
  once (event, handler) {
    if (!listeners[event]) listeners[event] = []
    listeners[event].push(function h () {
      handler(...arguments)
      host.off(event, h)
    })
  },
  off (event, handler) {
    const i = (listeners[event] || []).findIndex(h => h === handler)
    if (i > -1) {
      listeners[event].splice(i, 1)
      if (!listeners[event].length) delete listeners[event]
    }
  }
})

// EXAMPLE

const e = emitter()

e.once('msg', msg => {
    console.log('once.msg: ', msg)
})

e.on('msg', msg => { // <- not firing
    console.log('on.msg: ', msg)
})

e.on('msg', msg => {
    console.log('on_1.msg: ', msg)
})

e.emit('msg' ,'See me?')
```

The first 'on.msg' handler does not fire at all, however if the 'once.msg' handler is moved below the other two everything fires smoothly, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `(listeners[event] || []).forEach(h => h(data))` will use an indexer starting at `0` and incrementing it for each item. When you delete an item (when calling `once` which calls `off`) the indexing is wrong and will actually skip the next item in line.

Easiest way to remedy this is to make a copy of the events:

```
(listeners[event] || []).slice().forEach(h => h(data));
```

Comment: following this answer, a simple solution would be to replace `listeners[event].splice(i, 1)` by `listeners[event][i] = function(){};`, disabling it without changing the indexes

Comment: Replaced the array with a ``Set``, seems to work fine now because there's no ordering. Thanks :D